Establishing a unique element in the proof that the dual of $\mathbb{R}$ as an additive group is $\mathbb{R}$.
In Deitmar's A First Course in Harmonic Analysis, the author proves that the dual of $\mathbb{R}$ (as an additive group) is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, since the group of characters is given by $x \mapsto e^{2\pi i x y}$ for $y \in \mathbb{R}$ (this is Proposition 7.1.1).
The proof begins:

Let $\varphi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{T}$ be a character. By continuity there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\varphi([-\epsilon, \epsilon]) \subset \{\operatorname{Re}(z) > 0\}$. Let $y$ be the unique element of $[-\frac{1}{4\epsilon}, \frac{1}{4\epsilon}]$ such that $\varphi(\epsilon) = e^{2\pi i \epsilon y}$.

I am failing to see either why such a $y$ exists, or why it should be unique. I assume that this has to do with what $\varphi(-\frac{1}{4\epsilon})$ and $\varphi(\frac{1}{4\epsilon})$ must be, together with some kind of continuity argument, but I don't see how the set-up tells us anything about the values $\varphi(-\frac{1}{4\epsilon})$ and $\varphi(\frac{1}{4\epsilon})$.

$y$ exists unique because it's $1/(2\pi\epsilon)$ times the argument of a complex number whose real part is positive. Such an argument would lie in $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ modulo $2\pi$, hence the range $[-1/(4\epsilon), 1/(4\epsilon)]$ modulo $1/(2\epsilon)$ after making the substitution.
